# How can i make 3 of my website pages display 3 different woocommerce products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my website, I have different pages that can be accessed through the navigation bar at the top of the website(Like every other website), on the pages TX-21, TX-20, and TX-10. I want to show 1 product on each page.

I have tried working with the permalinks, but I can't seem to find a solution through this, because the only possibility is to make a "shop" page, which is what I want to avoid in a sense.
I also can't make one of the three pages my "shop" page, because then all of the products will be displayed on that page.

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many solutions are possible here,

The easy way to do it :

When you create a product on Woocommerce, a single page for the product is automatically created. So you can just go to appearance -> menus and select your product by choosing "product" on the left side. it will create a new menu element and linked to your single product page.

Also, if you to customize every product page as you want, the best way is to create 3 page " TX-21, TX-20, TX-10" and query what you want inside all of them by using a template-file.